# Getting gfortran 10 from Fedora 31

Tags: fedora, gfortran

I tried to install gfortran 10 from Fedora 31.
Follow https://fortran-lang.org/learn/os_setup/install_gfortran
`sudo dnf install gcc-gfortran` leads to gfortran 9

I tried to download from https://fedora.pkgs.org/33/fedora-x86_64/gcc-gfortran-10.2.1-3.fc33.x86_64.rpm.html
the download link file leads to `Failed to install file, not supported` from graphic interface :(

or `bash: ./gcc-gfortran-10.2.1-9.fc33.x86_64.rpm: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` from terminal with root.

Is there any way to install gfortran-10 from Fedora?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can of course always compile GCC from source, it is not that hard and the script for getting [the prerequisites](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html) is included (`./contrib/download_prerequisites`).

The easiest way is to download one of the snapshots https://gcc.gnu.org/snapshots.html and follow [the instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC). You do not even have to have admin rights, you can do it privately in your home directory.

---

Check whether there is a repository with additional GCC versions for your distro. For example, on my OpenSuSE, I have packages for GCC 7, 8, 9, 10 and 11. And they can be installed concurrently.

---

Regarding:

```
bash: ./gcc-gfortran-10.2.1-9.fc33.x86_64.rpm: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

You cannot run a rpm file in bash, you have to install it using `rpm -i` or using your higher level package manager.

Comment: Build gcc-10.x.x from source https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zIwm4j1obAPYbQqva9LDNMrvCpR39sgu/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The file you downloaded is an RPM package, not an executable. You would normally install it with `dnf install ./gcc-gfortran-10.2.1-9.fc33.x86_64.rpm` from the command line. However, that package is for Fedora Linux 33, and you're running 31. Occasionally this works, but generally installing packages from new releases on older releases isn't supported.

If, for some reason you can't upgrade to Fedora Linux 33 for your whole system, one approach is to use the [toolbox](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-silverblue/toolbox/) utility to make a containerized workspace using a F33 container image. Then, you can install the version of gfortran you want into that (with `dnf install gcc-gfortran`).

You could also use F34 (out tomorrow) but note that that has gcc 11.